# laravel user registration by roles in many to many relationship

Tags: laravel

In my application, I have two types of users **"title"** & **"notary"**.

I have connected some users to these roles by **many to many relationship** [there is a table `'role_user'`, which is pivot table and contains `'user_id'` from **users table** and '`roles_id'` from **roles table**].

I have made seeds to give the users, specific roles. till this point my application is fine.

Now, I want to set a users role, when he registers [the idea is to select a radio button before registration].

When someone registers, he will be given selected role. How to do this in many to many relationship?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission package for manage roles.

Comment: application is far away from using spatie @JinalSomaiya. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Okay, then follow https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Answer (score 2):

When user selects radio button then you will get that value and call a relationship on user to assign role.

```
 $role = $request->role //get this value from radio
```

Since this is registration method so you will first create user and call a relationship to attach role.

```
$user = User::create($request->only('required fields ...'));
```

Now attach role to created user.

```
$user->roles()->attach($role);  //this line is actual answer to your question
```

This will fill your pivot table with user role

Make sure you have defined `roles()` method in `User.php` model

```
public function register (Request $request){
    $role = $request->role; //this is not necessary to save role value in variable you can get it directly from request object
    $user = User::create($request->only('required fields'));
    $user->roles()->attach($role or $request->role); // you can get role value directly from $request object. 

}
```

Comment: i'm getting your answer but where should i put $role = $request->role in registercontroller @Afraz

Comment: Your radio button should have name `role` and values should be that you want. When user will submit the form then radio button's selected value will be sent in `$request` to your controller method. Then you can get role value in start of your method.